# Mathematica: FindFit for NIntegrate of ParametricNDSolve

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, curve-fitting

I've seen several answers for quite similar topics with usage of ?NumericQ explained and still can not quite understand what is wrong with my implementation and could my example be evaluated at all the way I want it.
I have solution of differential equation in form of ParametricNDSolve (I believe that exact form of equation is irrelevant):

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{n'[t] == g/(1/(y - f*y) + b*t + g*t)^2 - a*n[t] - c*n[t]^2, n[0] == y*f}, {n}, {t, 0, 10}, {a, b, c, g, f, y}]
```

After that I am trying to construct a function for FindFit or similar procedure, Nintegrating over function n[a,b,c,g,f,y,t] I have got above with some multiplier (I have chosen Log[z] as multiplier for simplicity)

```
Func[z_, a_, b_, c_, g_, f_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Log[z]*(n[a, b, c, g, f, y][t] /. sol), {t, 0, 10}, {y, 0, Log[z]}]
```

So I have NIntegrate over my function n[params,t] derived from ParametricNDSolve with multiplier introducing new variable (z) which also present in the limits of integration (in the same form as in multiplier for simplicity of example)

I am able to evaluate the values of my function Func at any point (z) with given values of parameters (a,b,c,g,f): Func(0,1,2,3,4,5) could be evaluated.
But for some reasons I cannot use FindFit like that:

```
FindFit[data, Func[z, a, b, c, g, f], {a, b, c, g, f}, z]
```

The error is:

> NIntegrate::nlim: y = Log[z] is not a valid limit of integration.

I`ve tried a lot of different combinations of ?NumericQ usage and all seems to lead nowhere. Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance and sorry for pure English in the problem explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to define your function:

```
sol = n /. 
  ParametricNDSolve[{n'[t] == 
     g/(1/(y - f*y) + b*t + g*t)^2 - a*n[t] - c*n[t]^2, 
    n[0] == y*f}, {n}, {t, 0, 10}, {a, b, c, g, f, y}]

Func[z_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ, 
  f_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[Log[z]*sol[a, b, c, g, f, y][t],
      {t, 0, 10}, {y, 0, Log[z]}]
```

test: `Func[2, .45, .5, .13, .12, .2]` -> 0.106107

I'm not optimistic you will get good results from `FindFit` with a function with so many parameters and which is so computationally expensive.

Comment: Thank you! But I can evaluate function Func even without introducing ?NumericQ variables and such variables also do not help me to get FindFit - the NIntegrate error remains. You are also right about computational expenses of such method but I will need it to be done just several times for my experimental data and I don`t want to write some Fitting algorithm myself - I believe it will be even slower/buggy.

Comment: be sure to clear old definitions. That error is due to `NIntegrate` being evaluated with symbolic `z` .